# Do supermarkets spray fruit to keep it from rotting?

Tags: nutrition, pesticides

Many people wash their fruits because they say that supermarkets put a chemical spray on them to keep them nice for a long time without rotting. (They are concerned that eating food with that spray is unhealthy for our body.)

Is this true?

Comment: Are you referring to [1-Methylcyclopropene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Methylcyclopropene)?

Comment: @femtoRgon Maybe...

Comment: *Many people wash their fruits because they say supermarkets put a chemical spray on them to keep them nice*... I have never heard anyone say that. Can you backup your claim with references? This site is for debugging notable claims, not for hearsay.

Comment: Surprisingly I **have heard this**. But I rinse my fruit because it's just dirty not to. Have you ever picked up a few Apples then put them back?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you asking if fruits are sprayed with preservatives? Are you asking if they're sprayed specifically by supermarkets? Are you asking if the spray is harmful to one's health?

Comment: @Flimzy second question. Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Your question asks about "supermarkets", but I have interpreted that as synecdoche - that you really mean to ask about the whole fruit supply chain, and not just the retailers at the end of it.*

Yes, the agricultural industry uses sprayed chemicals to prolong the shelf-life of food.

I list two examples below - but there may be many more.

I haven't listed pesticides that may still be on the fruit, on the grounds that is generally to increase yield, not extend shelf-life.

### Wax

Apples, cucumbers, rutabagas, lemons and turnips are just some examples of fruits and vegetables that are sometimes covered in food-grade waxes such as [Shellac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnauba_wax) or [Carnouba wax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnauba_wax)

> Both of these waxes are “food-grade waxes” and have been used on food for decades. The FDA has labeled both of these waxes safe for human consumption. Both of these natural waxes are complex mixtures and contain some of the same components found in the wax of an apple.

- Source: [Is there wax on apples?](http://www.bestfoodfacts.org/wax-on-apples/)

### 1-MCP

Commercial products such as [RipeLock](http://www.agrofresh.com/web/portal/ripelock-technology) and [SmartFresh](http://www.agrofresh.com/web/portal/smartfresh-technology) contain [1-Methylcyclopropene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Methylcyclopropene) (1-MCP) which prevents ethylene from acting as a hormone to promote ripening, thus extending the shelf-life.

## Wash Fruit *Anyway*

The [FDA recommend washing fruit](http://www.fda.gov/food/resourcesforyou/consumers/ucm114299). We have a related question about the best way to do this: [Do fruit/vegetable washes effectively remove pesticides?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5865/23)

The reason given is to remove *dirt*, but especially *microbes*. Even if you doubt the existence of sprayed chemicals, or are confident that the FDA has correctly assessed that trace amounts are not a danger, you should wash your fruits and vegetables anyway.

Comment: I've personally have never heard about supermarkets doing this though it is common knowledge that farmers do this. I wonder why the blame shifted to supermarkets?

Comment: ruta*what*? - its called a swede!

Comment: @Jamiec: I agree, but my *reference* called a rutabutabunga, or whatever, and I didn't want to have to provide another reference to translate that to English.

Comment: @slebetman: I imagine, without evidence, it is derived from dismissing the fruit found in supermarkets (that are generally from big supply chains) from the fruit found in farmer's markets which (presumably) are less likely to have been treated this way.

Comment: I note, without taking sides, there are arguments that these treatments *improve health* by making fruits and vegetables cheaper and more widely available.